# Does the first NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGatheringNotification notification guarantee that metadata has been retrieved from iCloud?

Tags: ios, notifications, icloud, icloud-api

According to apple docs, `NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGatheringNotification` is posted when the receiver has finished with the initial result-gathering phase of the query.

Aside from cases with no internet connection, does the first `NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGatheringNotification` notification guarantee that metadata has been retrieved from iCloud?

For example, if I have "sample.txt" in iCloud, if I received the first `NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGatheringNotification` notification, "sample.txt" will be included in the results.

On the other hand, if "sample.txt" does not exist in iCloud, its nonexistence is guaranteed on the first `NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGatheringNotification` notification if it is not included in the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Apple people, the answer is NO, the notification does not guarantee that values have been retrieved from iCloud successfully.

`NSMetadataQuery` can return empty results immediately after an account change or the first login.